# How to launch a asp.net web app from another one?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to launch a web app from another web app but it doesn't work, I've got hundred of errors :

> One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure that your project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the 'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false.
>
> The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> [assembly: global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorCompiledItemAttribute(typeof(TestWebApp.Pages.Pages_Index), @"mvc.1.0.razor-page", @"/Pages/Index.cshtml")]

The steps that lead to the prob :

- Create a new project with a ASP.Net Core Web Application targeting netcoreapp2.1
- Create a second project with a ASP.Net Core Web Application targeting netcoreapp2.1
- Reference the first project in the second project
- In the second project, inside the Main I call the main of the first project
- Launch the second project and you should see the errors

My goal here is to be able to modify my second webapp and add components without modifying the first one.

Comment: If your intent is to open one web app from other, there are other ways to do so. First, to think of your design, does these two web apps are designed to be on its own? Like both will be hosted separately and could run without other's dependencies? If so, then you can have other web app as a url navigation/redirection. but if you are looking for reference, why would it need to be two web apps? cant they be, under the same project or two class projects and use as needed in your web UI project? can you explain your need for this reference via main class file?

Comment: I need my main application to run on its own and the second one to be dependent on the main.
My goal here is to developed a webapp (the main one) and not modified it afterwards and be able to modify the second one.